# how to add the session values in a html table row one after the other on submitting the form in php

Tags: php

Thanks in advance,Actually In my application I have a form with "Add to cart" submit button so whenever I am submitting a form the text field values should pass through the session and it should add one below the other like a row in a different html table below the form, not in mysql table.Something like this as below

```
Exam Name | Venue Name | Date of Exam | Price  | No.of Exam 
PMP       | venue1     |23-12-2016    | $40    | 2
ITIL      | venue2     |24-12-2016    | $30    | 2

My code as below

<?php
session_start();
$course = $_POST['course'];
$venue = $_POST['venue'];
$date = $_POST['Userdate'];
$price = $_POST['txtprice'];
$noExams = $_POST['num_exams'];
$_SESSION['course'] = $course;
echo $_SESSION['course'];

?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <form  method="post" action="shopping.php"> 
   <table><thead>
          <th>Exam Name</th>
          <th>Venue Name</th>
          <th>Date of Exam</th>

          <th>Price / Course</th>  
          <th>Number of Exams</th>            
          <th>Add to Cart</th> 
         </thead>
         <tbody>
          <tr>      
             <td>
                <select name="course">   
                  <option value="">--Select--</option>            
                  <option value="ITIL Foundation">ITIL Foundation</option>
                  <option value="PMP">PMP</option>
                  <option value="">Prince 2 Foundation</option>
                </select>           
             </td>    
              <td><input type="text" name="venue" id="venue" required="required"></td>        
              <td><input type="text" name="Userdate" id="Userdate" required="required"></td>   

              <td><input type="text" name="txtprice" id="Userdate" required="required"></td>
              <td>
                <select name="num_exams" required="required">   
                  <option value="">--Select--</option>            
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>           
             </td>
             <td><input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit"></td>

         </tr></tbody>

  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo the Php values to the form input fields. For example for the venue field you need to add the value attribute like following:

```
<td><input type="text" name="venue" id="venue" required="required" value="<?php echo $venue;?>"></td>
```